# Extraction of subsets by date and intervals from a dataframe with a specific date format

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Given the following dataframe:

```
|      ID             |     date                       |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          1          |     2022-02-03 22:01:12+01:00  |
|          2          |     2022-02-04 21:11:21+01:00  |
|          3          |     2022-02-05 11:11:21+01:00  |
|          4          |     2022-02-07 23:01:12+01:00  |
|          5          |     2022-02-07 14:31:14+02:00  |
|          6          |     2022-02-08 18:12:01+02:00  |
|          7          |     2022-02-09 20:21:02+02:00  |
|          8          |     2022-02-11 15:41:25+02:00  |
|          9          |     2022-02-15 11:21:27+02:00  |
```

I would like to optimise the code of the following function:

Returns all rows whose date (YYYY-MM-DD) matches the date passed by parameter.

```
# Function to search by exact %Y-%m-%d date
def select_exact_date(df, date):
    date = pd.to_datetime(date, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    date_dt = date.date()
    # Create a copy of the original df
    subset = df.copy()
    # Creates a temporary column to store the values related to the specific date
    subset['tmp_date'] = subset['date'].apply(lambda a: a.date())
    mask = (subset['tmp_date'] == date_dt)
    df = df.loc[mask]
    return df
```

Result:

```
select_exact_date(df, '2022-02-07')
#Output
|      ID             |     date                       |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          4          |     2022-02-07 23:01:12+01:00  |
|          5          |     2022-02-07 14:31:14+02:00  |
```

I hope you can help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where does the `date` string parameter actually come from? I ask because if it's far-removed from user input or file content, it should have been converted to a datetime object earlier than where you show it.

Comment: @Reinderien is added by the user and shall always be in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'.

Comment: OK, but that's not exactly what I'm asking. Added by the user how? `input()` five functions ago? Read from a file into a different dataframe? Etc.

Comment: @Reinderien That doesn't matter, I'm asking for help to optimise the code of the function. Treat it as a black box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That doesn't matter

Context does matter. A strict interpretation of the site guidelines would consider your question off-topic due to insufficient context, since code can't be reviewed in a vacuum (a black box, as you put it). If you think context doesn't matter in a review, then you might as well say that reviewing the code doesn't matter, either.

In this case, it *does* matter where your `date` comes from, because you've failed to type-hint it so it could be anything that `pd.to_datetime` [accepts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

> arg: int, float, str, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, Series, DataFrame/dict-like

I'm going to make a sweeping assumption: that your `date` parameter is a `datetime.date` object, as it should be.

It seems that you've left the `date` column full of `datetime.datetime` timezone-aware objects. Working with Pandas will be made more difficult than it needs to be using this approach. Consider instead coercing the date column to an actual Pandas UTC datetime, avoiding `apply()` like the plague:

```
from datetime import date
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

# ...

    f = StringIO(
'''ID,date
1,2022-02-03 22:01:12+01:00
2,2022-02-04 21:11:21+01:00
3,2022-02-05 11:11:21+01:00
4,2022-02-07 23:01:12+01:00
5,2022-02-07 14:31:14+02:00
6,2022-02-08 18:12:01+02:00
7,2022-02-09 20:21:02+02:00
8,2022-02-11 15:41:25+02:00
9,2022-02-15 11:21:27+02:00'''
    )
    df = pd.read_csv(
        f,
        parse_dates=['date'],
        index_col='ID',
    )

    date_to_select = date(2022, 2, 7)
    utc_dates = pd.to_datetime(df.date, utc=True).dt.date
    matching_rows = df[utc_dates == date_to_select]
```

If it matters that the exact local timezone's day boundaries be respected you'll need to get more creative.